# How can I save the order of the tree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqtree

It's a little bit complicated to explain. I would like to **save the position on which the tree has been repositioned**, and then when the **user opens the page again it will appear the way the user left it** (I do not want to make it only for one user but for all, because only the admin is going to have access to it anyway). it sounds ununderstandable, that's why I made an example right below:

**Simplifying**:

1 - Get the order of the tree's elements that the user left

2 - Send it to my server as a text file (Probably Ajax)

[image]

Thus, when I reload the page or/and clean up the cache, it will still be in that position that I left. I want the "position" to be sent as a text file using ajax to my server. Is there a way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 
 
 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="./tree.jquery.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./jqtree.css">
 <script src="./jquery-cookie/src/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
  
 

 <style>
  body{overflow-x:hidden}
  #navdata{width:auto; height:auto; flex:1; padding-bottom:1px;}
  #navgrid{width:50%; height:200px; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:scroll; border:solid 1px #79B7E7; background-color:white;}
         #header{background-color: #79B7E7; width:100%; text-align: center;border: 1px solid white;}
        .jqtree-element{background-color:#DDEBF7;border: 1px solid white;height:23px;color:red;}
        .jqtree-tree .jqtree-title {color: black;}         
       ul.jqtree-tree ul.jqtree_common {margin-left: 0px;}
        ul.jqtree-tree .jqtree-toggler {color: #325D8A;}
        ul.jqtree-tree .jqtree-toggler:hover {color: #3966df;text-decoration: none;}
        .jqtree-tree .jqtree-title.jqtree-title-folder {margin-left: 0;}
        span.jqtree-dragging {background: #79B7E7;}
        ul.jqtree-tree li.jqtree-selected > .jqtree-element,ul.jqtree-tree li.jqtree-selected > .jqtree-element:hover {background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#BEE0F5), to(#79B7E7));}
    </style>

 
</head>
<body>
 <div id="navgrid">
      <div id="header">Header</div>
  <div id="tree1"></div>
 </div>  
</body>


 <script type="text/javascript">
  var ExampleData = {}; 
    ExampleData.data = [
     {
         label: 'node1', id: 1,
         children: [
             { label: 'child1', id: 2 },
             { label: 'child2', id: 3 }
         ]
     },
     {
         label: 'node2', id: 4,
         children: [
             { label: 'child3', id: 5 }
         ]
     }
 ];
 
 ExampleData.getFirstLevelData = function(nodes) {
    if (! nodes) {
        nodes = ExampleData.example_data;
    }

    var data = [];

    $.each(nodes, function() {
        var node = {
            label: this.label,
            id: this.id
        };

        if (this.children) {
            node.load_on_demand = true;
        }

        data.push(node);
    });

    return data;
}

ExampleData.getChildrenOfNode = function(node_id) {
    var result = null;

    function iterate(nodes) {
        $.each(nodes, function() {
            if (result) {
                return;
            }
            else {
                if (this.id == node_id) {
                    result = this;
                }

                if (this.children) {
                    iterate(this.children);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    iterate(ExampleData.example_data);

    return ExampleData.getFirstLevelData(result.children);
}
 
 $('#tree1').tree({
     data: ExampleData.data,
     autoOpen: false,
     dragAndDrop: true
     
 });
    
 </script>

</html>
```

Comment: What technologies are you using server side?

Comment: Does it matter? :), Because I just need to send it, The problem is to get the positions put it in a text file and dispatch it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I  think earlier i got your question wrong. This will be your answer.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//var data is a dynamic json file that should be created in the backend.
var data = [
    {
        label: 'node1', id: 1,
        children: [
            { label: 'child1', id: 2 },
            { label: 'child2', id: 3 }
        ]
    },
    {
        label: 'node2', id: 4,
        children: [
            { label: 'child3', id: 5 }
        ]
    }
];
$('#tree1').tree({
    data: data,
    autoOpen: true,
    dragAndDrop: true
});


console.log($('#tree1').tree('toJson')); //This will give you the loading jqtree structure.

    $('#tree1').bind(
    'tree.move',
    function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // do the move first, and _then_ POST back.
        event.move_info.do_move();
        console.log($(this).tree('toJson')); //this will give you the latest tree.
//        $.post('your_url', {tree: $(this).tree('toJson')}); //this will post the json of the latest tree structure.
    }
);


});
```

Comment: replace this json into a file of your default file.

Comment: Thanks, So basically it will transform the positions into a JSON file?

Comment: I tested it it showed me in JSON wow, thank you so much you're a genius

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, but what can I use to receive that and create a JSON file containing that, in a tomcat server 5.5 (it can be in the same directory where the page's at) ?

Comment: Always wish to help you. Sorry, not good in tomcat with Javaservlets. if you are comfortable, i shall share you php code, to achieve the task later today.

Comment: Sure, I will be glad if you share it with me :)

Answer (score 1):

Updating the Code with HTML/JS/PHP with

**Folder Structure**

```
Root Folder
      stackoverflow-2.html
      libs/jquery/jquery.js
      libs/jqtree/tree.jquery.js
      libs/jqtree/jqtree.css
      scripts/stackoverflow-2.js //custom script created by me
      json/stackoverflow-2.json //json file output to create the nodes and children.
      php/stackoverflow-2.php //php commands to write.
```

**stackoverflow-2.html** //same as your reference. Changed only mapping of the library files.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/jqtree/tree.jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/jqtree/jqtree.css">
    <script src="scripts/stackoverflow-2.js"></script>
    <style>
        body{overflow-x:hidden}
        #navdata{width:auto; height:auto; flex:1; padding-bottom:1px;}
        #navgrid{width:50%; height:200px; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:scroll; border:solid 1px #79B7E7; background-color:white;}
            #header{background-color: #79B7E7; width:100%; text-align: center;border: 1px solid white;}
            .jqtree-element{background-color:#DDEBF7;border: 1px solid white;height:23px;color:red;}
            .jqtree-tree .jqtree-title {color: black;}         
            ul.jqtree-tree ul.jqtree_common {margin-left: 0px;}
            ul.jqtree-tree .jqtree-toggler {color: #325D8A;}
            ul.jqtree-tree .jqtree-toggler:hover {color: #3966df;text-decoration: none;}
            .jqtree-tree .jqtree-title.jqtree-title-folder {margin-left: 0;}
            span.jqtree-dragging {background: #79B7E7;}
            ul.jqtree-tree li.jqtree-selected > .jqtree-element,ul.jqtree-tree li.jqtree-selected > .jqtree-element:hover {background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#BEE0F5), to(#79B7E7));}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="navgrid">
      <div id="header">Header</div>
        <div id="tree1"></div>
    </div>  
</body>
```

**stackoverflow-2.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({                            /*Makes a ajax call and gets the contents from the json file*/
    method:"get",
    url:"json/stackoverflow-2.json"
}).success(function(data){

    $('#tree1').tree({
    data: jQuery.parseJSON(data.tree),
    autoOpen: true,
    dragAndDrop: true
});

});
    $('#tree1').bind(
    'tree.move',
    function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // do the move first, and _then_ POST back.
        event.move_info.do_move();
         $.post('php/stackoverflow-2.php', {tree: $(this).tree('toJson')}); //this will post the json of the latest tree structure.
    }
);

    });
```

**Initial stackoverflow-2.json**

```
{
    "tree": [
        {
            "label": "node1",
            "id": 1,
            "children": [
                {
                    "label": "child1",
                    "id": 2
                },
                {
                    "label": "child2",
                    "id": 3
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "node2",
            "id": 4,
            "children": [
                {
                    "label": "child3",
                    "id": 5
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**stackoverflow-2.php**

```
<?php
file_put_contents("../json/stackoverflow-2.json", json_encode($_POST)); //calls the file and enters the new tree structure.
```

Code tested in my localhost.

Comment: That's amazing, I'm gonna test it right now, thanks alksander +1

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the jqtree documentation you can have your code like this.

```
var lastOpenedByAUser = 0; // make a ajax call to get this value. This value is also stored in database or any file in your server end if the last user clicked another node.

$('#tree1').tree({
data: data,
autoOpen: lastOpenedByAUser //shall be 0 for node-1, 1 for node-2
 });
```

Make sure, you run this $('#tree') code only after the code your ajax code is completed.